# How do I share context between my service and my controller in an express api to enable proper logging in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking to be able to pass information between my controller and service to enable proper logging. I am currently refactoring my app from just using controllers to switch to having all business logic within services. However, I am confused how to share logger context between the service and the matching controller function. Take the below controller function for example. When I translate this to use controller and service, everything between the logs 'creating new comment' and 'user notification created' would be moved into my service I believe. Now lets say I want to add the created user notification to my logger context so that when an error is thrown, the user notification is passed with the logger in the next(error) to my errorHandler middleware so it can be logged as context for the error. How is this generally handled? Also, I want to log everything that happens as a part of the current request with a unique request id. Right now I do this by adding "req" as a property of the logger to get the request id I added in a middleware, but with this method when I refactor I have to pass it to every service as a dependency or every method of the service. I feel like since both of these problems I'm facing are fairly common, there must be a standard approach but I have not for the life of me been able to find an acceptable solution. Any suggestions or resources you can point in my direction helps, thank you!

```
const createComment = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   let chLogger;
   try {
      const { commentText, createdByUserId, postId, postUserId } = req.body;
      chLogger = logger.child(req, 'commentController.ts', 'createComment', {
         createdByUserId: createdByUserId,
         postId: postId,
      });
      chLogger.debug('Creating a new comment');
      const newComment = await Comment.create(commentText, createdByUserId, postId);
      chLogger.verbose('Comment created', { comment: newComment });
      // Create user notification for the comment if comment was succesfully
      if (newComment) {
         await UserNotification.create(newComment.commentId, postId, 'comment', postUserId, createdByUserId);
         chLogger.debug('User notification created');
      }
      res.status(201).json(newComment);
   } catch (error) {
      req.chLogger = chLogger;
      next(error);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to share logger context

```
const logger = createLogger(); // You can use your own logger setup

const createComment = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { commentText, createdByUserId, postId, postUserId } = req.body;
        const chLogger = logger.child(req, 'commentController.ts', 'createComment', {
            createdByUserId,
            postId,
        });

        chLogger.debug('Creating a new comment');

        const newComment = await CommentService.createComment(
            commentText,
            createdByUserId,
            postId,
            chLogger // Pass the logger to the service
        );

        chLogger.verbose('Comment created', { comment: newComment });

        if (newComment) {
            await UserNotification.create(
                newComment.commentId,
                postId,
                'comment',
                postUserId,
                createdByUserId,
                chLogger // Pass the logger to the service
            );
            chLogger.debug('User notification created');
        }

        res.status(201).json(newComment);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

// CommentService module:
const CommentService = {
    async createComment(commentText, createdByUserId, postId, logger) {
        logger.debug('Service - Creating a new comment');
        
        
        return newComment;
    },
};
```

then to log request information setup middleware

```
const express = require('express');
const uuid = require('uuid'); 

const app = express();

// Request logger middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.requestId = uuid.v4(); 
    const requestLogger = logger.child(req, 'requestLogger', {
        requestId: req.requestId,
    });
    req.logger = requestLogger; // Attach the logger to the request object
    next();
});
```

now you can access req.logger in both controller and service methods

Comment: Thanks! So is it standard practice then to pass a logger into every service method like this? Also I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet sorry.

Comment: yes following those practices, you can preserve a clean separation of concerns between your controller and provider layers while being capable of share context and log request-unique data effectively.

Comment: btw you can accept the answer and up vote now

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it! I always felt bad that I couldn't upvote other peoples answers. What I ended up doing was just adding in the OpenTelemetry ExpressInstrumentation into my app which automatically creates a span that a unique request id can be extracted from in the logger. Either solution works though!